# Careers 2.0 profile doesn't have the option to include Programmers StackExchange profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Is anyone having the same issue? 
I can only see stackoverflow and meta, skeptics, mathematics, but not programmers. Also the reputation from any of the sites don't get upgraded, only if I do an edit/remove/readd.

Comment: Looking at your accounts tab, you don't seem to *have* a programmers account, do you? Did you forget to associate them?

Comment: In fact I have a programmers account, and now a stackapps account as well, neither of them are showing.

Comment: When did you associate them?  Careers only updates every ~24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be working now.  Your programmers account was not associated with your other accounts, which is why it didn't show up at first.  After you associated them, it can take up to 24 hours for Careers to pull in the new information.

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed working now. (Though update seems more than 24hours, but anyway, point is it's ok)